# Examples of languages with complex "formules de politesse"

Tags: phonetics, french, formal-semantics, grammar-formalism

French uses [complex word arrangements](https://www.lalanguefrancaise.com/general/formule-de-politesse-email-lettre-de-motivation/) to say "best regards" and "yours sincerely" to finish well written letters, i.e.:

*Nous vous prions d’agréer, Monsieur, l’expression de nos sentiments respectueux et dévoués.*

We beseech you to agree, Sir, the expression of our respectful and dedicated sentiments.

- Can you please give examples of other languages that use complex phrases as standard?
- Can you explain why a language type would shy from brevity? (I am bilingual so I understand from daily use, although you can surprise me!)

Comment: This question is likely to be closed as "too broad" because "Can you please give examples of other languages that use complex phrases as standard?" is an open-ended question. How many example languages would satisfy the question - one, ten, a hundred? I'd venture to say that *all* languages have politeness forms that don't maximize brevity.

Comment: Isn't it Indonesian or Javanese that have entirely stratified sociolects of politeness, so much that it's not just idioms but entire vocabularies that change?